# AdHoc Cache in Jasper Reports server

Tags: jasperserver

I am having some reports in Jasper Reports Server developed using Jasper Studio. The data is being loaded from the Rest API. I want to decrease the load time and make the report load faster. Is there any way I could achieve that?
My data is being displayed in Charts in the report.

**What I have tried?**

I have tried looking into [ad-hoc cache](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-ad-hoc-cache)  but could not integrate it. The guide provided is for **v4.7** of the Jasper report server. I am using v7 of the server and it is running in a docker container.

Is there any way I could decrease the load time of reports? If Ad-Hoc Cache is an option, then how can I make it work in v7 of Jasper Server?

Thanks